# Why I get wrong char array when I use WideCharToMultiByte?

Tags: c++, winapi

Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int iBuffSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, result_msg.c_str(),
        result_msg.size(), buffer, 0, NULL, NULL);

    buffer = static_cast<char*>(malloc(iBuffSize));
    ZeroMemory(buffer, iBuffSize);

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, result_msg.c_str(),
        result_msg.size(), buffer, iBuffSize, NULL, NULL);

    string result_msg2(buffer);
    free(buffer);

    throw runtime_error(result_msg2);
#else
    throw runtime_error(result_msg);
#endif
```

`result_msg` is `std::wstring` for unicode, and `std::string` for the multi-byte character set.

For Multi-byte character set:

[image]

For Unicode character set:

[image]

Comment: `std::string::size()` returns the number of characters, not including the zero terminator. When you convert to Unicode, you ignore the zero terminator. The destination string is not zero-terminated, and when you convert it to a string, it'll just pick up garbage. Use the [`std::string` c'tor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22b7w38.aspx) that takes an explicit length argument.

Comment: `std::vector` is to be preferred over malloc. Which you should not use in C++ anyway. You are expected to use `new` in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified the input string size as `result_msg.size()`, which does not include the terminating null character, and so the output won't be null-terminated, either.  But when you convert `buffer` to a `string`, you are not specifying the size of `buffer`, so the `string` constructor expects a null terminator.  Without that terminator, it is grabbing data from surrounding memory until it encounters a null byte (or get a memory access error).

Either use `result_msg.size() + 1` for the input size, or specify `-1` as the input size to let `WideCharToMultiByte()` determine the input size automatic. Either approach will include a null terminator in the output.

Or, keep using `result_msg.size()` s the input size, and use the value of `iBuffSize` when converting `buffer` to a `string`, then you don't need a null terminator:

```
string result_msg2(buffer, iBuffSize);
```

Comment: I don't know how the `wstring` and `string` hold their valus, therefore I will use `++iBuffSize;` instead of `-1`. Thank you.

Comment: No. Use -1. `c_str()` is null terminated. Futher, don't get too hooked on increment operators. If -1 was not available, you'd pass `iBuffSize + 1` to avoid changing the meaning of `iBuffSize`.